# How to display firebase data in a list in MIT App Inventor?

Tags: firebase, app-inventor

I am making an app in MIT App Inventor wherein I need to let users make new entries into the database and there should be a screen in my app where I can display all the entries in a list.
You can think of this as a feed mechanism similar to the feed systems of any social media app.

**Sample data:**

```
FirebaseDatabase
--id89677687
  --name: randomname1
  --randomdata: randomdata1
--id89748687
  --name: randomname2
  --randomdata: randomdata2
--id89836587
  --name: randomname3
  --randomdata: randomdata3
```

According to this data, I would want to display all the id fields and their subfields in the form of a list. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: There are some tutorials on this topic. What have you tried so far? What trouble did you run into? Please edit your question, explaining where you need help. Connecting to database? Authentication? Presentation layer? As it is now, your question is too broad, and [risks being closed as such](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: This question is not related in any way to mit-scratch. Please remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**: I found inbuilt elements in the MIT App Inventor and also found multiple tutorials on fixing this issue.